# fgets adds \0 or \n at the end of the input?

Tags: c, fgets

I've some doubts about fgets. From what I know, it adds "\n" at the end of the string, and not "\0". So if I write this code:

```
fgets(buff,2,stdin);
printf("%s",buff);
```

So fgets reads two characters, I give as input "y", so buff should be "y\n". I'd expect printf to print y and add a line, while it prints "y" without adding a line. Can you explain why?

Comment: it adds "\0" at the end of the string, and not "\n".

Comment: Did you check the [fgets doc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) to see what it says?

Comment: You have to press ENTER (the `'\n'`) to *get out* of `fgets()`. In your specific case, `buff[0] == 'y'` and `buff[1] == 0`. The `'\n'` is still waiting in the *keyboard buffer*.

Comment: @pmg Well, more precisely, you need to press Enter to send the text you typed to *stdin* (if you are in line buffered mode, as you normally are in a console application). `fgets` itself will return at full buffer without waiting for Enter, it just can't get that full buffer for external reasons without user pressing Enter (normally).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
char * fgets ( char * str, int num, FILE * stream );
```

Reads characters from input stream and stores them as a C string into str until (num-1) characters have been read or either a newline or the end-of-file is reached, whichever happens first.

A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character by the function and included in the string copied to str.

A terminating null character ('\0') is automatically appended after the characters copied to str.

Comment: thank you so much. Now I've another problem, if "int num" is "2", I input a character e.g. "y", and then I do another fgets, the second one doesn't work. Is this because the memory has bufferized "\n"?

Comment: You may do a fllush(stdout) before next fgets from stdin

Comment: @DebasishJana: Why to flush `stdout` when reading from `stdin`?

Comment: @alk A `fflush(stdout);` insures synchronization on the display.  `printf("%s",buff);` might not print when one expects.

Answer (score 1):

It *must* terminate the string, so yes it will always add `'\0'` at the end. However, `fgets` might not always add the newline, if it doesn't fit. I recommend [this reference page for `fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).

Answer (score 1):

According to man page it clearly given :

```
 char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
```

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream 
>   and
>          stores  them  into  the buffer pointed to by s.  Reading stops after an
>          EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read, it is stored into the  buffer.
>          A '\0' is stored after the last character in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

fgets() adds \0 at the end but it reads the string with \n if it exists in the file

i have such thing after reading string:
"guitar\n\0\U00000004\xd5..."

my file had string with word "guitar" and \n after it
so, as u see it read the word with "\n" and added "\0" to the string

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32284667)